# Guitar volume/tone pots

Tags: electric-guitar

Looking at this [wiring diagram](http://www.dimarzio.com/sites/default/files/diagrams/AT300.pdf) I see there are two 500k-w pots and one 500k-d pot.
My question is what is the difference between the two pots (500k-w and 500k-d) and what should I ask for when I go to an electronic shop. Does the -w/-d make a difference of 500k pot is enough ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-w *probably* refers to audio taper pots and -d to linear taper.

Audio taper pots are usually used for volume so that the change in volume over the travel of the pot is equal.

Read [here](http://www.generalguitargadgets.com/faq/40-technical-questions/174-what-does-pot-taper-mean-audio-log-linear) for a more expansive explanation.